# How to Build AutoComplete feature?

Tags: trie, application-design, web-application-design

Features like
[image: Google Auto Complete]

For Example
I have a field called people names, when user type in, we will show all options which matches what user inputs.

My first question:

```
which one should maintain trie tree, frontend, backend or both?
```

Second question:

```
No matter front end or back end, when will trie tree be loaded?
If trie loaded on start, million of entities loaded take a lot time, and huge data in memory.
If trie loaded once user searched, each time user typed is a DB call and a Rest call, which also consumme a lot resources. And at first search, user will see no options till he did once, which is bad user experience.
```

If you have ideas, look forward to know!